# How to set and check a boolean flag in python

Tags: python, boolean

I'm trying to do something like this with a boolean:

```
/* ... other stuff */
loggedDocument = false
for line in inFile:
  if (line.find( /*something*/ ) != -1):
    println("FOUND DOCUMENT: %s" % line)
    loggedDocument = true
  if (loggedDocument == false):
    /* do something else */
```

But I keep getting invalid syntax errors.  I googled but couldn't find a simple boolean example, any ideas?

Comment: false and true should be upper case

Comment: You also don't need brackets on if statements in python.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're looking for `True` and `False` (note the capitals). Also the more pythonic way to write the last line is `if not loggedDocument` instead of `if loggedDocument == False`. Edit: And BTW, the `println` is not Python a builtin Python function; are you looking for `print()`?

Answer (score 4):

The Booleans are spelled `True` and `False`.

Make sure you have your whitespace right.

And remove the parenthesis after `if`, they're not needed.